# How to make a list of cells' values where adjacent cells match a value?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to make a comma-delineated list of all the Cells with an adjacent column of a specific value.

I have one sheet like this:

Sheet1

```
       A          B     
1 |Entity    | Attribute
------------------------
2 |Car       | Brand
3 |SUV       | Clearance
4 |Truck     | Clearance
5 |Truck     | Height
6 |SUV       | Length
```

I'd like to list all the A-Column values where a specific Attribute shows up. For instance:

Sheet2

```
         A           B
  1 |Attribute  |Entities  |
  --------------------------
  2 |Clearance  |SUV,Truck |
```

I know I can use VLOOKUP to get one of those values like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:B,1)
```

But is it possible to produce a list of matching cells?

Comment: Take a look at [this link](http://eimagine.com/how-to-return-multiple-match-values-in-excel-using-index-match-or-vlookup/) There is also further down an example for a comma delimited list. But you'll first need a place for the looked up values and gather them afterwards.